# Kickstart PXE boot ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, pxe-boot, automated-install, kickstart

I am trying to do a fully automated install of Ubuntu 10.04

My pxelinux.cfg/default file looks like this -

```
label linux 
     kernel ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
     ipappend 2
     append ks=http://172.16.20.254/ks.cfg ksdevice=bootif pressed/url=http://172.16.20.254/ubuntu.seed initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz ramdisk_size=16432 root=/dev/rd/0 devfs=mount,dall rw --
```

My kickstart file is never requested when I look at my apache logs. There is no activity in the apache logs. Yet I can request the apache logs by going to http://172.16.20.254/ks.cfg

WHen I boot, the server starts a PXE install, DHCP succeeds and then it stops at the nameserver input box. NO activity in logs.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Dave

Comment: What TFTP-daemon software are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Kickstart and preseeding are both technologies for performing automated installations. Preseeding is native to Debian-derived distributions like Ubuntu. Kickstart is native to Red Hat. There is a [kickstart compatibility layer](http://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2006/01/msg00372.html) that translates kickstart instructions into preseed instructions. However, it is [poorly documented](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility) and I doubt it is well tested. Instead of struggling with it, I recommend translating your kickstart file into a pressed file and using that. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/appendix-preseed.html) is the documentation.